# Pandas: get value of an index in multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe :

```
data = {'id': [1,1,2,3],
        'name': ["Noemie","Elena", "Lize", "Patrick"],
        'value': ["pink", "blue", "red", "yellow" ]}
```

So I gather all the rows with the id "1" thanks to `df.set_index(["id","name"])`

My columns id and name become indexes, I wonder if is it possible to get for example the value "Noemie"

Knowing that, before multi-indexing I can have it with

`df.loc[0].at["name"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.index.get_level_values` to get the desired index column you want and do comparison.

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('name') == 'Noemie']
 
          value
id name        
1  Noemie  pink
```

Or if you just want the index value

```
df.index[df.index.get_level_values('name') == 'Noemie'][0][1]
Out[30]: 'Noemie'
```

Answer (score 1):

If need select first row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) then get second value of indices by `name[1]` - python count from `0`:

```
data = {'id': [1,1,2,3],
        'name': ["Noemie","Elena", "Lize", "Patrick"],
        'value': ["pink", "blue", "red", "yellow" ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(["id","name"])
print (df.iloc[0])
value    pink
Name: (1, Noemie), dtype: object

print (df.iloc[0].name)
(1, 'Noemie')

out = df.iloc[0].name[1]
print (out)
Noemie
```

For select second row:

```
print (df.iloc[1])
value    blue
Name: (1, Elena), dtype: object

print (df.iloc[1].name)
(1, 'Elena')

out = df.iloc[1].name[1]
print (out)
Elena
```

EDIT: If need all values of index if `id=1` use:

```
print (df.loc[1])
       value
name        
Noemie  pink
Elena   blue

s = df.loc[1].index.tolist()
print (s)
['Noemie', 'Elena']
```

Comment: And to get the value Elena, i tried print(df.iloc[0].name[2]) but it doesnt work. I don't understand how it works... Could you explain please ?

Comment: @jmht - so need filter by `Noemie` ? Not ouput is `Noemie` ?

Comment: Oh thank you, last question if i had more values and i wanted get all the value with a for loop, here i want have Noemie and Elena thanks to a loop, how can i get it?

Comment: df.iloc[0].name[1] to print Noemie is what i want

Comment: @jmht - added solution for both values to answer.